# Game Center push notifications not working after move to iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, ios9

I have recently updated my Game Center game for iOS9. The push notifications worked most of the time in iOS8, but now do not at all in iOS9. Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: OK. It seems to be working again.